# StackOverflow while instancing a struct containing custom get of a Bitmap

Tags: c#, graphics, instantiation

I am trying to add some graphics to the program I'm writing and for that I want to combine two bitmaps. I want to avoid to combine them explicitly, so I wrote some code to handle the combination each time it's called.

```
public struct Map
{
    ...
    public Bitmap Display 
    { 
        get 
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(this.Display))
            {
                g.DrawImage(this.Background, new Rectangle(0, 0, Display_Width, Display_Height));
                g.DrawImage(this.Room_Grid, new Rectangle(0, 0, Display_Width, Display_Height));

                g.Dispose();
            }

            return this.Display;
        } 
        private set { } 
    }
    ...
}
```

I had previous success with similar code but this time it throw a StackOverflow after compiling and instancing the struct.

Why does this happen and how can fix the problem while maintaining functionality.

Edit:

Thanks everybody, so far.

I now understand the issue. I'd like to fix it without needing to create a transfer bitmap out of memory concerns (not sure why, the collector only runs every 10 to 20 seconds) and I'd like to avoid a method to since it will always be the combination of a static background with the changing foreground. I'd need to add the method call each time before display the update image which seems clunky if I could do it when asking for the image.

Comment: Note that the last line of you `Display` property _getter_ is `return this.Display;`. What do you think that's going to do? It will Invoke the `Display` property getter. Which will do it again and again. Each call will use up stack space till it runs out

Comment: Work with a local `var bitmap = new Bitmap(Display_Width, Display_Height);` and then create a `Graphics.FromImage(bitmap)` etc. etc. and finally `return bitmap;`. You can drop the setter. Note that accessing property getters are assumed to be low-cost operations. Better make a method `CreateDisplay()`. Or at least cache the bitmap in a backing field, so that repetitive calls don't re-create the image everytime.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the first actual line of code in the getter for your `Display` property:

```
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(this.Display))
```

This is an explicit infinite recursion that blows your stack 100% of the time. Not only is it bad practice to read a property's value from its own getter, it is almost always an error to do so. So much so that it should result in a compiler error.

I assume that you didn't intend to do this, that there's a `display` or `_display` or some other field that holds an actual bitmap, and you mis-typed. Just for completeness, here's what it *should* look like (if I'm reading your intent correctly):

```
private Bitmap? _display = null;

public Bitmap Display
{
    get
    {
        if (_display is not null)
            return _display;
        // Create the bitmap with whatever properties you need here
        _display = new(Display_Width, Display_Height);

        // now initialize it
        using Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(this.Display);
        g.DrawImage(this.Background, new Rectangle(0, 0, Display_Width, Display_Height));
        g.DrawImage(this.Room_Grid, new Rectangle(0, 0, Display_Width, Display_Height));

        return _display;
    }
}
```

---

Which is all well and good if the various values never change, but I'm going to go out on a limb and assume that at least `Background` is slightly dynamic. If so, you need to dispose of (and null) `_display` any time the relevant values change.

For instance, let's say you're compositing a background bitmap for a game where the background updates whenever you move from one room to another. It's slightly quicker to cache all the statics in the scene into a bitmap that only gets updated on room change. And while there are a ton of ways to go about it, the ideal is probably to reuse the same bitmap instance as long as the room's background (or the screen size) doesn't change.

So... let's respond to those changes by getting rid of the existing `_display` bitmap and rebuild it the next time we need it.

```
private Bitmap? _background = null;
public Bitmap? Background
{
    get => _background;
    set
    {
        if (!ReferenceEquals(_backgroud, value))
        {
            Interlocked.Exchange(ref _display, bmp)?.Dispose();
            _background = value;
        }
    }
}

// Use whatever your default width is:
private int _displayWidth = 1920;
public int DisplayWidth 
{
    get => _displayWidth;
    set
    {
        if (_displayWidth != value)
        {
            Interlocked.Exchange(ref _display, bmp)?.Dispose();
            _displayWidth = value;
        }
    }
}

// Same for default height.
private int _displayHeight = 1080;
public int DisplayHeight
{
    get => _displayHeight;
    set
    {
        if (_displayHeight != value)
        {
            Interlocked.Exchange(ref _display, bmp)?.Dispose();
            _displayHeight = value;
        }
    }
}

// And finally, the cached display bitmap
private Bitmap? _display = null;
public Bitmap Display
{
    get
    {
        if (_display is not null)
            return _display;

        // Create new bitmap.
        _display = new(DisplayWidth, DisplayHeight);
        
        // Get the image bounds
        GraphicsUnit units = GraphicsUnit.Point;
        RectangleF bounds = _display.GetBounds(ref units);
        
        // Or just do this:
        // Rectangle bounds = new(0, 0, DisplayWidth, DisplayHeight);

        // Draw the contents of the new bitmap
        using Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(_display);
        g.DrawImage(Background, bounds);
        g.DrawImage(Room_Grid, bounds);

        return _display;
    }
}
```

---

NB: sprinking `this.` all through your code is a distraction. Use it when there's a conflict with a local variable or parameter name, otherwise it's just pointless noise. Better yet, use a naming convention that ensure that you'll never have to deal with name collisions of that nature and you'll never need use `this.` again.